# Laravel5.4 ¿Cómo traer la información de un arreglo a la vista de blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

## Descripción

Se cuenta con dos tablas
**noticias y notas**
Todo perfecto con el controlador ya que el buscador encuentra lo que está en la tabla de **noticias** y sus datos  estan guardados en la variable $noticia.El problema es con los campos de la **tabla notas:** `('nombre_nota', 'editor_nota','duracion_nota', 'bloque_nota')` La pregunta es como muestro la los datos de la relación en un `<td>{{$buscar['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>` con blade.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Controlador

```html
public function busqueda(Request $request){
  $ntc_turno = $request->input('noticiero_turno');
  if ($ntc_turno) {
    $noticia=Noticia::with('notas')->whereHas('notas', function($query) use($ntc_turno) {
    $query->where('nombre_nota','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
})
    ->orWhere('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
    ->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
    ->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
    ->paginate(2);

  return view('noticia.buscar', array('noticia'=>$noticia) );

}else{
     $noticia = Noticia::paginate(3);
     return view('noticia.buscar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
}
}
```

### Vista

```html
@if (isset($noticia))
 <div class="panel panel-success">
 <div class="panel-heading">Resultado de busqueda</div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <div class='table-responsive'>
 <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
 <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Turno</th>
 <th>Fecha</th>
 <th>nombre_nota</th>
 </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
  @foreach($noticia as $buscar)
  <tr>
  <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_programa']}}</td>
  <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_turno']}}</td>
  <td>{{$buscar['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>
    <tr/>
            @endforeach
    <tr>
    </tr>
 </tbody>

 </table>
<center></center>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="{{url('noticia/buscar')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Reiniciar busqueda</a>
  </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes iterar a través de las notas, tal y como lo hiciste con las noticias, ten en cuenta que por el tipo de relación podrías obtener más de un registro:

```
    @foreach($noticia as $buscar)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$buscar->noticiero_programa}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar->noticiero_turno}}</td>
      <td>{{$buscar->noticiero_fecha}}</td>
      <td>
         @forelse($buscar->notas as $nota)

           {{$nota->nombre_nota}}
           {{$nota->editor_nota}}
           {{$nota->duracion_nota}}
           {{$nota->bloque_nota}}

         @empty

           ¡No hay notas!

         @endforelse
      </td>
    <tr/>
    @endforeach
```

Ya como quieras organizar tu tabla o HTML, te lo dejo.